# How to specify 'git send-email' to send mail on a specific patch?

Tags: git, git-send-email

How to specify 'git send-email' to send mail on a specific patch?

I have 4 commits but I haven't done a 'git pull'.
When I do 'git send-email', it will send out 4 emails (1 patch for each commit).

How can I configure git send-email so that it can send out email just for the last commit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git-send-email` takes arguments specifying the patches to send. For example,

```
git send-email HEAD^
```

will create a patch for the last commit on your current branch. Similarly if you are formatting patches first with `git-am`, you can specify only the single patch file you want to send.

For more information on how to specify revisions, see `man git-rev-list`. The common methods you'll probably care about:

- `<commit1>..<commit2>` means everything after  up to
- `<commit>^` means the commit before `<commit>`
- `<commit>~5` means the commit five commits before `<commit>`

Comment: Note that git-send-email accepting git-format-patch / git-rev-list parameters is quite new feature (require quite modern git)

Comment: Ah, thanks, Jakub, didn't know that. I'm more of a push-pull guy. I imagine `git-format-patch` has been taking the `git-rev-list` parameters for a while, though, so there should be an alternate solution.

Comment: The variant with commits you advised oesn't work. `git send-email fb1171d274971b5c7984622836fbec1c144e0ea2 --annotate` tries sending 2 patches, and not even single of them is `fb1171d…`.

Answer (score 2):

The question was asking about a "specific patch", so many may come here to find how to send email for a spefic commit, everywhere in the log history.
For this case answer may be:

git send-email -1 b7ed62c8d882fecaf70da813a0494b2f8265d544 -to trullallero@tralala.com

Where b7ed62c8d882fecaf70da813a0494b2f8265d544 is the commit i want o send as a single [PATCH] whatever is his position in the log history.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this shoud be working:

```
git send-email -1
```